# DownloadFileCompleted Event won't show simple MessageBox

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to implement the WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted event, mainly to delete the file if the download has been canceled.

DownloadFileCompleted event:

```
private void _web_client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            //Delete the file in here
            MessageBox.Show("Download cancelled!"); // Doesn't work
            File.WriteAllText("output.txt", "Test string"); //Works
            throw new Exception("Some Exception"); //Program doesn't crash
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Download succeeded!"); // Works
        }
}
```

FormClosing event:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
         _web_client.CancelAsync();
}
```

So if I just let the download finish, the "Success MessageBox" will be shown. But if I close the application while it's downloading, no MessageBox will be shown and the program also won't crash, although I throw an exception which isn't handled. On the other hand, the text file gets created and filled with the test string.

So why is this not working? And how am I supposed to handle possible exceptions thrown by the File.Delete call?

(Note that I am using WebClient.DownloadFileAsync)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MessageBox.Show` is not working because the form that was supposed to be the owner of the MessageBox was already disposed. if you set the `owner` parameter of the `Show` method to to the current instance of the form you will get a [`System.ObjectDisposedException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Now, what you can do instead is this:

```
private void _web_client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        //Delete the file in here
        MessageBox.Show("Download cancelled!");
        File.Delete(@"path\to\partially\downloaded\file");
        this.Close(); 
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Download succeeded!"); // Works
    }
}



private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (_web_client.IsBusy)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this._web_client.CancelAsync();
    }       
}
```

Comment: When I thought about it I came up with another question: You said that "the form that was supposed to be the owner of the MessageBox was already disposed", but doesn't the form get disposed **after** the FormClosing event, unless I set e.Cancel to true?

Comment: Yes, it gets disposed after the `OnFormClosing` event. The call happens [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,3564).

Comment: So what I meant was that the MessageBox should still work, since the form is not disposed yet in the FormClosing event!

Comment: You're trying to show the message box after the OnClosing event.